# Script to insert JSON data into MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mongodb

I currently have a JSON file titled "data.json". In this file, I only have an array of people's names, like this:

```
"data":
[
    {
        {
        "name":"John",
        "age":30,
        }

        {
        "name":"Mark",
        "age":45,
        }   
    }
]
```

My goal is to write a script to insert this data into mongoDB. Could I write this directly in my JSON file? How would I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to structure the `JSON` from the javascript and sent it off to something (service, PHP/C#/Java/Node.js etc.) which can actually insert it into the database. You cannot write something within the `JSON` file itself to do this.

Comment: Alright. So based on what you have said, in which language/file would I go about creating that script? I know you said I would have to "send" it to something, such as javascript (I'm assuming)? How would I write the script itself?

Comment: You would structure the json in the javascript file and then send it off to a service. That service would be the one writing the structured json received from the javascript into the database. The JSON file does nothing but hold data. It's only a way to structure data. There are many different types of services you can write in many languages. That choice is up to you.

Comment: I'm curious what your app/project is supposed to do. MongoDB and the JSON file are data storage destinations. You shouldn't need to keep track of data in both sources.

Comment: Andy, I am currently trying to create a data file, and then a script to insert that data into MongoDB. In more detail, my script should insert an array of JSON objects.

To do this, I initially created a JSON file and made an array there (as I posted above). Now, I am trying to somehow write a script to read that data into MongoDB. Is this the incorrect method?

Answer (score 2):

You can make this script with NodeJS

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"; // Your mongodb url here

enter code here`MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  var myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
  dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("The document got inserted.");
    db.close();
  });
});
```

You can also insert it manually through the GUI program or directly through your MongoDB command line

```
db.collection.insert('"data":[{"name":"John","age": 30},{"name": "Mark", "age": 45}]')
```

Comment: Interesting. I was reading this webpage:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

I was wondering if I could create a new Javscript file, and write my script in there? Then, I could execute my JS file directly from Mongo?

Comment: I am not using MongoDB that often so I never encountered with those scripts. I usually do things manually or with node. You can check this thing out on Youtube. Hope you will find the best way to do that!

Answer (score -1):

create a post route using nodejs to add data to your collection in mongodb

Comment: A post route... so by that, I'm guessing you mean create a new JS file, and I can create my script there? Hmm. I'm still a bit confused.